# Thread runs slow when Invoke UI-Element

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface, dispatcher

i am programming a benchmark tool, that reads a bunch of variables from a local server in a thread.

```
            int countReads = 1000;

            Int64 count = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < countReads; i++)
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
                DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

                session.Read(null, 0, TimestampsToReturn.Neither, idCollection, out ReadResults, out diagnosticInfos);

                DateTime stop = DateTime.Now;
                Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;

                TimeSpan delay = (stop - start);

                double s = delay.TotalMilliseconds;
                count += (Int64)s;

                Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() =>
                {
                    progressBar1.Value = i;
                }));
            }

            double avg = (double)count / countReads;

            Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(() =>
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(avg);
            }));
```

I am calculating the timespan it took to proceed the read and getting the average timespan at the end.

```
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

            session.Read(null, 0, TimestampsToReturn.Neither, idCollection, out ReadResults, out diagnosticInfos);

            DateTime stop = DateTime.Now
```

if i run the code without updating the progressbar it took about 5ms average.
but if i run it with

```
            Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() =>
            {
                progressBar1.Value = i;
            }));
```

it takes about 10 ms average.

My question is, why is the timespan higher when using the progressbar?
i am just calculating the timespan for the read. Not including the progressbar update.

Is there any way to evacuate the ui-painting so that it doesn´t effect my read-timespan?

Thanks for your help.

Best regards

Comment: An extra 5ms does seem a long time for a simple context-switch, propety set and the issuing of some paint messages.  Is the GUI message queue quite busy?  Anyway, try BeginInvoke so you don't have to wait if it is.

Comment: Use Stopwatch instead of DateTime.Now

Comment: BeginInvoke is same behavior. I am wondering, because if i replace the read-request with a Thread.sleep(20) the timespan is nearly exact 20 ms. with and without using the progressbar. but is there any way to update the ui without getting a longer timespan for the read-request?

Comment: @Marat: i used Stopwatch before. Same behavior.

Comment: session.read() - is there any way in which this call can require or generate GUI messages, (grasping at straws, now).  Horrible thought - there is no COM STA, by any chance?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stop using `Invoke` to transfer progress information to the UI thread. Publish the progress information to a shared data structure or variable and have the UI thread poll for it using a timer on a reasonable interval. I know it seems like we have all been brainwashed into thinking `Invoke` is the be-all method for doing worker-to-UI thread interactions, but for simple progress information it can be (and often is) the worst method.

A polling method using a timer on the UI thread offers the following benefits.

- It breaks the tight coupling that `Invoke` imposes on both the UI and worker threads.
- The UI thread gets to dictate when and how often it should update the progress information instead of the other way around. When you stop and think about it this is how it should be anyway.
- You get more throughput on both the UI and worker threads.

I know this does not directly answer your question as to why `session.Read` appears to run slower. Try changing your strategy for updating progress information from a push model (via `Invoke`) to a pull model (via a timer). See if that makes a difference. Even if it does not I would still stick with the pull model for the reasons listed above.

Comment: This sounds like such a better strategy. A simple example would be really helpful. I'll try myself too.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what MSDN says about [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx)

> Executes the specified delegate **synchronously** on the thread the Dispatcher is associated with.

So, basically, `Dispatcher.Invoke` blocks until the dispatcher thread as handled the request.

Try `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` instead.

Comment: Right, this makes sense if current thread is associated with Dispatcher

Comment: i tried BeginInvoke and got the same behavior. also it would be ok if the Thread is blocked at the part where i call the dispatcher. i just want the part for the read-request to work without delay. if the thread blocks for updating the gui it should not influence the timespan for the read, or am i wrong?

Comment: Right. Try measuring the time elapsed to do 10000 reads and divide the result by 10000 to get a better average time per read. Measuring reads one by is probably why you got such irrelevant results.

Answer (score 1):

I came 9 years late to the party, but I think this is an even easier solution: Just wait until the progress bar value reaches a certain threshold before updating it. In my example, I refresh the toolbar every fifth of the maximum value.

```
private static int progressBarMaxValue = -1;
private static int progressBarChunkSize = -1;

        public static void progressBarSetNotRealTimeValue(ProgressBar progressBar, int argNewValue)
        {
            if (progressBarMaxValue != -1)
            {
                if (argNewValue < progressBarChunkSize)
                {
                    //Threshold not reached yet, discard the new value.
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Allow the update, and set the next threshold higher.
                    progressBarChunkSize += progressBarChunkSize;
                }
            }

            if (Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground)
            {
                progressBar.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    if (progressBarMaxValue == -1)
                    {
                        progressBarMaxValue = progressBar.Maximum;
                        progressBarChunkSize = progressBar.Maximum / 5;
                    }

                    progressBar.Value = argNewValue;
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                progressBar.Value = argNewValue;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If current executing thread is associated with Dispatcher you are using - `Invoke()` will block this thread so in this case try out using [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke.aspx) it will do the job asynchronously.

[MSDN, Dispatcher.Invoke Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591593.aspx):

> Invoke is a synchronous operation; therefore, control will not return
>   to the calling object until after the callback returns.

BTW, just of interest try out `DispatcherPriority.Send`

Comment: i used Stopwatch before. Same behavior.

Comment: What about BeginInvoke? Invoke will block thread associated with Dispatcher, so in case whe current thread associated - you got unnecessary timeout

Comment: OP has tried it.  I'm baffled as to why an Invoke/BeginInvoke should affect the timing of the session.read() call.  The OP has even raised the priority of the read thread!

Comment: DispatcherPriority passed in Invoke/BeginInvoke is not the same as changing CurrentThread.Priority